# Firefox starts most websites in dark mode

Tags: kde, firefox

I have my system (KDE) configured in dark mode as I like these themes, but I don't know why, firefox opens most websites in dark mode (I don't even know how the website knows that I am using a system-wide dark-mode). This applies to google, but also gitea and many other websites:

[image]

On the other side, Chromium opens these website using the standard light mode. How could I ask Firefox to use the light mode of the website by default? (dark mode hurts my eyes if I have enough light around me) It would actually be cool to also be able to configure this on a per-website basis.

**EDIT**
Actually, I think firefox configures the media query `prefers-color-scheme` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393880/how-do-i-detect-dark-mode-using-javascript I need to find a way to change it. So far I tried to *create* an entry `ui.systemUsesDarkTheme` set to 0, but it does the wrong thing: the firefox theme is turned into light mode, while the website stays dark.

**EDIT**

Solved thanks to Quasimodo pointing to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1363994#answer-1473215

In url `about:config`, change `layout.css.prefers-color-scheme.content-override` into `1`. More details:

- 0 => Force a Dark background
- 1 => Force a Light background
- 2 => Follow the System theme (default in Firefox 94)
- 3 => Follow the Browser toolbar theme (default in Firefox 95+)

Comment: Oh cool, actually I tried it using "0", but for light theme it's 1. Thanks! Feel free to write an answer if you like.

Comment: In my case I needed to refresh the page two times or more before it works...

Comment: [I have written a detailed answer.](https://powerusers.codidact.com/posts/286042).